# ¿Como ejecuto un comando como root desde un .desktop?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-9

Llevo tiempo intentando  hacer un acceso directo .dekstop que ejecute un comando como root. Con sudo no vale porque estoy en debian.
Seria como un `su -; [comando]` pero eso, claro, no funciona ni en la terminal ni en los .desktop
También se me había ocurrido hacer un archivo más elavorado para ejecutar el script y ejecutarlo desde el .desktop, pero aun así no se como hacerlo.
A ver si alguien sabe alguna manera.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Respuesta si utilizas KDE (BEST escritorio :3)**

Quiero ejecutar konsole, terminal de KDE como root simple, reemplazas konsole por tu comando.

```
kdesu -c 'konsole'
```

**Respuesta si utilizas algún escritorio con gtk (gnome,mate,xfce...)**

```
gksu -c 'comando'
```

> El comando tiene que estar entre comillas, las comillas específica donde comienza y termina el comando

Comment: grasias amigo :33